# RedirectToAction without querystring MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a bit of code here in my mvc app that performs a redirect.

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { slug = viewModel.Farm.Slug });
```

This redirect to the url

```
/Farm/Details?slug=the-farm-name
```

What i'd like it to do is this

```
/Farm/Details/the-farm-name
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a route matching to the above in the Routes Table in your global.asax.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that... The whole routing thing is taking a bit of getting used to.

Comment: @James: What helped me was to remember that routes are two-way: You can provide a URL and it returns parameters, **and** you can give them parameters and it generates a URL. If there are no routes that can generate a URL, it falls back to query string hackery.

Answer (score 1):

you are using default routing, where you have defined one parameter "id".
Change your code to return

`RedirectToAction("Details", new {id = viewModel.Farm.Slug })`;

or add new route.