# How to redirect to a specific URL from within a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controllers, redirecttoaction

I am  trying to redirect user to a specific address, after they submit a form.
What I use is the code below in my Content controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("Business", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Content", action = "Business", Id = business.BusinessID }));
```

It creates a URL like this : 
**www.x.com/Content/Business?Id=13**

What I really want is something like this:
**www.x.com/Content/Business/13**

I really don't want the query string to be separated with ? but to be consistent with the rest of the URLs.

Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: See answer from this question:

[RedirectToAction without querystring MVC][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336536/redirecttoaction-without-querystring-mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should actually be the same thing, but the thing to note is in the Global.asax file, where I setup my routing table, I need to have the following piece of code so that my desired result be produced. Notice the third url parameters {parameter}

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{parameter}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Tokens", action = "Index", parameter = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

with that code, I only need to use the variable "parameter" instead of "Id" in my code:

```
return RedirectToAction("Business", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Content", action = "Business", parameter= business.BusinessID }));
```

It is very important to use the same name for your variable as you defined in MapRout() function.

Doing this, I have my desired result :

**www.x.com/Content/Business/13**

Comment: This is correct - the name of the parameter defined in route should match the name of the property in `new { }`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

return RedirectToAction("Business" , "Content" , new { Id = business.BusinessID });

Comment: That does the same thing. You're just calling a different overload.

Answer (score 0):

For me, your line of code produces the link that you are expecting,is your routing setup OK?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I change the default naming for Id to parameter. I should change that in my controller function to the same thing. The problem was solved that way.